# How to disable inline edit on cell CLICK in PHPmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin when I browse table content CLICKing on certain cell starts this cell data editor.

How to avoid that? I didn't find no config options for this!

Comment: It looks like a new config option called `$cfg['GridEditing']` is planned for an upcoming "4.0.0" release of phpMyAdmin. See lem9's comment at https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3522109&group_id=23067&atid=377411

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit  js/makegrid.js and replace `$(c).is(".grid_edit")` with `$(c).is(".grid_edit**_no**")`

Comment: Why edit the config files manually when there's a setting to disable that? :S

Comment: @Andrew afaik this was basically the only way to do it at the time of this post. Thankfully we don't have to do that now!

Comment: Thanks, needed this hack for PHPMyAdmin3, which does not listen to the GridEditing config option.

Answer (score 22):

As of phpMyAdmin 4.0.0, `double-click` is now the new default for cell editing. If you want, you can disable cell editing completely OR change it to single click by adding a line to `config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['GridEditing'] = 'disabled'; //disabled cell/grid editing completely
$cfg['GridEditing'] = 'click'; //single-click editing
$cfg['GridEditing'] = 'double-click'; //default value. No need to specify this except for maybe readability purposes
```

Source: [phpMyAdmin Documentation on $cfg['GridEditing']](https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#cfg_GridEditing)

**Update:** You can also simply adjust GridEditing from within the phpMyAdmin user interface by navigating to "Settings > Main Panel > Browse Mode > Grid editing: trigger action"

Comment: This should be the one and only answer. Not manually editing config files.

Answer (score 4):

Old post I know but still receiving visits. Simply goto your settings in phpmyadmin:

```
https://yoursite/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/prefs_forms.php?form=Features
```

Uncheck the first box in the page (Enable Ajax) You want to disable this.

No need to edit javascript files, seems quite extreme. I can only assume this option is recent.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant part is `find("td.data").click(function(c)`, if you'd return false here the editing would be stopped. I'm posting here because I found this page in a quest to maintain this functionality but on doubleclick.

If you also want to enable this on doubleclick just replace:
`find("td.data").click(function(c)`
with 
`find("td.data").dblclick(function(c)`

in `/js/makegrid.js.`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the below is not a proper solution to the problem but is a workaround..

though i do not find any downside of it but it may restrict some other feature of *phpmyadmin*

- go to the *js* directory under your *phpmyadmin* directory
- rename `makegrid.js` to something like `mmakegrid.js`