# PHPMyAdmin row editing

Tags: phpmyadmin

thanks for any help pointed out here :)

I am having an issue with a new version of PHPMyAdmin.

First let me paint the picture,

I went away from work for Xmas hols, upon returning found out that there had been and update on all versions of PHPMyAdmin. This new version looks ok but here is my main problem. Ever since I have used PHPMyAdmin I have been able to click anywhere on a table row to select it, now it has been changed so that if i click a row it automatically opens the inline editor!!!! WTF!!! i don't want to edit it, i want to select it!!! how can this is turned off since this could already be done and i never used it anyway. I have no control over the versions of PHPMyAdmin that are used they are all installed by Fasthosts.

Im sure I am not the only dev who as come across this problem, can anyone help me??

I suppose if not i can run an old version of PHPMyAdmin, but this is not idea since there may be other security issues in the older versions that have been fixed in the newer version.

Comment: Possible dupliate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771577/how-to-disable-inline-edit-on-cell-click-in-phpmyadmin?rq=1  This should resolve your issue though.

Comment: yer same issues, but the solution will never work since i don't have access to the PHPMyAdmin installation files.

Comment: I dont think you need the installation files. I believe you just need to edit the javascript...and/or rename it.

Comment: This has _nothing_ to do with php, so I changed the tags. Plus it has _nothing_ to do with implementation, which is what this place is to get help for, so voting to close it.

Comment: anyway to answer my own question you can stop this by disabling ajax in the setting -> features page within PHPMyAdmin! <-- in case anyone cares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find /js/makegrid.js.

The relevant part is find("td.data").click(function(c), return false here to prevent editing.

If you also want to enable this on doubleclick just replace: find("td.data").click(function(c) with find("td.data").dblclick(function(c)

Answer (score 2):

For phpMyAdmin version 4.0.5 you can set the grid editing option to disabled or double click (double click is actually the default now).

```
$cfg['GridEditing'] = 'double-click';
or
$cfg['GridEditing'] = 'disabled';
```

However to select the row with a single click, the makegrid.js file needs to be edited. In the initGridEdit function add the following code after line 1659

```
else {
// Custom code added to select row on single click
var $row = $cell.parent();
var $checkbox = $row.find('td input[type=checkbox]').first();
$checkbox.prop('checked',!$checkbox.prop('checked'));
$row.toggleClass('marked');
}
```

After the code is added, it will look something like this. Note that I left out some code to shorten this answer.

```
$(t).find('td.data.click2')
.click(function(e) {
    $cell = $(this);
    // In the case of relational link, We want single click on the link 
    // to goto the link and double click to start grid-editing.
    var $link = $(e.target);
    if ($link.is('.grid_edit.relation a')) {
        // OMITTED CODE...
    } else {
        // Custom code added to select row on single click
        var $row = $cell.parent();
        var $checkbox = $row.find('td input[type=checkbox]').first();
        $checkbox.prop('checked',!$checkbox.prop('checked'));
        $row.toggleClass('marked');
    }
})
```

I have only tested this solution when setting grid editing to double click. It will most likely not work if grid editing is disabled.